# ScheduledExecutorService: when shutdown should be invoked?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I use *ScheduledExecutorService* in my application. I need to use it from time to time in certain Utility class to run scheduled threads.

Is it a good design to hold *ScheduledExecutorService* in static field? Is it  a must to invoke ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown() in such case? What is the risk if I do not invoke shutdown?

That's what I thought to do:

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

public void scheduleTask(String name) {
        Future<?> future = futuresMapping.get(name);
        if(future!=null && !future.isDone())
            future.cancel(true);

        //execute once   
        Future<?> f = scheduledExecutor.schedule(new MyTask()), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        futuresMapping.put(name, f);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should always invoke shutdown() or shutdownNow(). If you don't do that your application might never terminate as there are still threads active (depending how you're terminating your app, whether it's in managed environment or not etc.).

Usually you would call shutdown() from some sort of lifecycle event method - such as from Spring's DisposableBean.destroy(), or if you're not using any framework just call it before exiting from your app.

Comment: I tried to add scheduledExecutor.shutdownNow(); in my ServletContextListener, but I get an error in tomcat log saying "The web application [/servlet] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.". How can I avoid this error? Thanks for help

Comment: shutdownNow() is non blocking call which would return immediately. You should call awaitTermination() after that which would block until thread pool actually down.

Comment: I tried, it did not work. Should I wait longer than 30 seconds? I wrote more details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930624/tomcat7-and-scheduledexecutorservice-shutdownnow
thanks

Answer (score 4):

Effective Java 2nd Ed says:

> And here is how to tell the executor to terminate gracefully (if you fail to do this, it
>   is likely that your VM will not exit):
>
> `executor.shutdown();`