# Tomcat 7 and ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat7, executorservice

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` to run scheduled threads.
I implemented `ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed` and invoked `ScheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow` and `awaitTermination`.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletcontextevent) {
    pool.shutdownNow(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
      // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
      if (!pool.awaitTermination(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
        System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
      pool.shutdownNow();
      // Preserve interrupt status
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }        
}
```

Still, I am getting the following error from Tomcat 7:

> SEVERE: The web application [/servlet] appears to have started a
>   thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely
>   to create a memory leak.

Can this log be ignored? Or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I mean, my thought is: Where do your responsibilities for doing cleanup stop? What else can be done here? Hit the box with a fire hose?
In all seriousness, what I mean to say is that it looks like you're doing just about all you can do... I'd ignore that error.

Comment: You may refer my previous post :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926356/scheduledexecutorservice-when-shutdown-should-be-invoked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure this error is related to your Thread pool? Judging by thread name 'Timer-0' it probably had been started by some sort of timer.

Also, you shutdownNow() should return you the list of Tasks that still await termination (see JavaDoc). You could build logic to wait more if list is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly shutting down your `ScheduledExecutorService`. However threads created by `ExecutorService` by default follow this naming convention: `pool-X-thread-Y`.

`Timer-0` threads are created by `Timer` class. Look for them in your code and libraries.

Comment: Does `shutDownNow()` wait for tasks that are scheduled or for tasks that are currently executing? Or Both? Is there a way to only wait for the tasks that are currently executing (say I don't want to wait for a task that I scheduled to execute in an hour but I do want to wait for a task that's currently in the middle of its `execute()` method)?